# Keras: InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [64,7,7,1] vs. [64,1] when trying to add ResNet with SVM classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, svm

I am trying to add a SVM layer to my ResNet model but I am getting the error `InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [64,1] vs. [64,7,7,1] [[node hinge/mul (defined at <ipython-input-39-8ab0138abfe4>:17) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_110660]`

My code is as follows:

```
base_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights="imagenet", input_shape=(img_height, img_width,3 ))

x = base_model.output
x = Sequential()(x)
x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dense(1, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0001))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Activation("linear")(x)
model = Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs = x)



model.compile(loss='hinge',
              optimizer='adadelta',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_generator, validation_data=validation_generator, epochs=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of ResNet is all feature maps you get from image you need to add a flatten layer (or global pooling if you want) before passing it to the fully connected part for classfication
from tf.keras.layers import Flatten

```
base_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights="imagenet", input_shape=(img_height, img_width,3 ))

x = base_model.output
# Flatten layer
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dense(1, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0001))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Activation("linear")(x)
model = Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs = x)
```